# except AppRegistryNotReady

Tags: python, django, django-admin

При разработке web-ресурса на django решил использовать приложение loginza. При настройке возникает исключение:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 9, in <module>
    django.setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 21, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-     packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 202, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/loginza/models.py", line 7, in <module>
    User = get_user_model()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-    packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py", line 137, in get_user_model
    return django_apps.get_model(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-    packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 199, in get_model
    self.check_models_ready()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-    packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 131, in check_models_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Models aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.
```

Читал документацию и проверил все варианты которые там указаны. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/applications/#troubleshooting
Результат тот же. Как только убираю приложение loginza из INSTALLED_APPS проект сразу запускается без проблем.

настройка manager.py:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE","tetrakub.settings.dev")
    import django
    django.setup()

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv):
```

Так же создана собственный класс User:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'registration.CustomerUser'
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1):

Видимо речь идет об этом пакете - [django-loginza](https://github.com/vgarvardt/django-loginza). Вот [здесь](https://github.com/vgarvardt/django-loginza/issues/33) описана такая же проблема как у вас. Автор пакета, судя по комментариям, исправил эту проблему, но судя по [pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-loginza/0.3.9) не залил обновления.
Попробуйте удалить пакет и установить dev-версию из GitHub:

```
pip uninstall django-loginza
pip install -e git+https://github.com/vgarvardt/django-loginza.git#egg=django-loginza
```

Comment: К сожалению это тоже не помогло. Результат не меняется. Решил попробовать использовать другой [проект](https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth).